# Sometimes my flutter app's icon got broken when refreshing list

Tags: android, flutter

I have a app and in the first page after login there is a list. Every works great but sometimes my app-bar icons became broken. I happens when i use refresh too much. Anyone have idea whats going on? There is no logic in icon , we used png and svg's.

Comment: Does this problem happen in the release version? If it happens in the debug version, some rendering problems are normal, try the release version.

Comment: in release apk, it happens